# How can I reset a device with broken lock button and touchscreen?

Tags: iphone, restart, touchscreen

I have an iPhone 4s on iOS 7. My lock (sleep/wake) button has been broken for months now and I've been using the assisted touch service to lock my phone screen ever since.

However, just over an hour ago my touch screen has decided to pack in also. I can bring up the menus from swiping up and down but anything else will not work, at all. So obviously I can't restart my phone by holding the power button and home button at the same time since the lock button doesn't work and I also can't turn it off as you must swipe the screen to select "power off". Has anyone got any ideas on how I can try to fix this?

Comment: How are you intending to **use** the device with broken buttons *and* screen? :)

Comment: that is my exact point. i can't use it. so i'm asking is there any way i can reset it via itunes or anything?

Comment: My point was what's the point in restoring it if you can't use it? :) (or are you hoping the restore will fix the problems?)

Comment: First, is it possible to turn on your flashlight? Second, are you able to get it so that the phone gives you "slide to shut down", like you mentioned? If so, perhaps you could create a custom gesture in guided access to perform the swipe.

Comment: @bassplayer7 The user's touchscreen and power button isn't working, so he can't do any of the above.

Comment: @FaizSaleem, I agree. However, they alluded to the fact that they could reach power off screen, so I was curious if anything was possible.

Comment: Could you clarify what you seek? How to diagnose and repair broken hardware is probably too broad a question for this site. I'm not sure we can clean up he diverse guesses, suggestions and all intentioned attempts to guess what you want the end result to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can go into your settings and turn on Assistive touch to turn your phone off.. The only way to turn it back on though is by using your charger.. If your phone decides it doesn't want to turn on anymore or charge like mine does then your stuck with a phone that wont turn on..

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried this, but theoretically it **should** work.

The jailbreak tool *redsn0w* has functionality which allows you to boot your device into *DFU mode* (Device Firmware Upgrade), which allows you to restore the device's firmware. Usually, one would use the *Home* and *Power* buttons to do such a thing. However, [these instructions](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2012/07/put-iphone-ipad-ipod-touch-in-dfu-mode-with-broken-home-power-button.html) should help you enter DFU mode without using the Home and Power buttons.

If you wanted to try a restart, you could try restoring to a backup. Not only would this fix any problems that may have developed, but it also requires rebooting the device, which may even fix the Power button.

Comment: Do you think there is a chance this would work on iOS 7?

Comment: @bassplayer7 DFU is completely separate from the firmware.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson, thanks for clarifying. I am unfamiliar with some of those things.

Comment: He said he cannot hold powerbutton and homebutton, else he could've done a hardware reset. -1

Answer (score -1):

you have to go into iTunes and restore it. plus she/he probably has a insurance plan and made a claim to get a new phone.

Answer (score -3):

Take out the battery and then wait ten seconds then put the battery back in and plug it in for one second to turn it on then it should work.

Taking out the battery can be hard. A speciall tool is needed to remove the back. Once that is complete use a small screw driver to remove the cable to the battery.

Answer (score -4):

take out the battery you guys really go around this the hard way lol.